# Pass data to jquery ajax start event

Tags: jquery, ajax, long-polling

In our master js file (A file presented on all pages) we add a callback to

```
$("body").ajaxStart
```

In the callback we show a ajax spinner and we hide it in the callback for ajaxStop

This have worked great, for all ajax calls.. BUT, we have got a new requirement that require us to use long time polling (Comet), for these request I do not want the spinner to show.

Can I pass data to the ajaxStart method somehow from the $.getJSON method call?

Comment: totally misread question initially

Answer (score 0, accepted):

global: false will not fire those events.
global: true is the default.

Comment: I'll mark as answer, BUT, it should be set to false, not true http://jsfiddle.net/ZakZ7/